# What will happen if two references try to add data exactly same time in List<T> colletion

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, collections

Check this function.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FindAccessibleDatabases()
{
    var connectionStrings = new List<string>();
    Parallel.For(0, _connectionStringCollection.Count, (index, loopState) =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionStringCollection[index]))
            {
                connection.Open();
                connectionStrings.Add(_connectionStringCollection[index]);
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException)
        {
        }
        finally         
        {
           connection.Close();
        }
    });
    return connectionStrings.ToList();
}
```

I am using Parallel.Foreach and adding values in a List from multiple databases at a time. I can use ConcurrentBag(It is tread safe while retrieving the data but adding is not mentioned) as I am just adding the data to the list, can use List.

Now if two threads try to add data to the list at exactly same time what will happen?

If it will create race condition, what if I use ConcurrentBag?

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: It's called a "race condition". Don't do it.

Comment: If I two try to retrieve I can understand, but while adding also will it happen?

Comment: The answer is really quite specific to what type of list implementation it is.  Don't see how this can be both C# and Java.

Comment: @Affe Agreed, this is clearly C#.  The answer happens to be the same in Java for `ArrayList<T>`, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You run the risk of **unspecified bad things** happening, like duplicates, one item not being added, corrupting the data structure, etc.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) says that `List<T>`'s Add method is not thread safe (well, specifically it says:

> A `List<T>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to
>   ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

).  Therefore you need to use a [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) or other form of thread synchronization around it, or you need to switch to a thread-safe data structure, like something in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

If you use ConcurrentBag's Add method, you don't need to worry about locking.  The data structure is explicitly thread-safe.

Comment: In same scenario if I use thread safe data structure, will this happen?
1. Locked the list
2. added first item ... At the same time put second item in queue
3. Unlock the list
4. Dequeued second item

Comment: Thread-safe data structures do not require locks for reading and writing.  If you have questions about how the System.Collections.Concurrent work, I'd recommend asking that separately or amending your question.